# Python requests not redirecting

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape word definitions, but can't get python to redirect to the correct page. For example, I'm trying to get the definition for the word 'agenesia'. When you load that page in a browser with [https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia](https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis), the page which loads is https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis, however in Python the page doesn't redirect and gives a 200 status code

```
URL = 'https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia'
page = requests.head(URL, allow_redirects=True)
```

This is how I'm currently retrieving the page content, I've also tried using `requests.get`
but that also doesn't work

EDIT: Because it isn't clear, I'm aware that I could change the word to 'agenesis' in the URL to get the correct page, but I am scraping a list of words and would rather automatically follow the URL rather than searching in a browser for the redirect by hand first.

EDIT 2: I realised it might be easier to check solutions with the rest of my code, so far this works with `agenesis` but not `agenesia`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("span", {"class": "ind"}).get_text(), '\n')
print(soup.find("span", {"class": "pos"}).get_text())
```

Comment: It should work ..

Comment: change URL to 'https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis'
capital letters in URL are giving this behavior

Comment: this worked for me
URL = 'https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis'
page = requests.get(URL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers mentioned before doesn't make your request redirect. The cause is you didn't use the correct request header. Try code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
}

page = requests.get('https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(page.url)
print(soup.find("span", {"class": "ind"}).get_text(), '\n')
print(soup.find("span", {"class": "pos"}).get_text())
```

And print:

```
https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis?s=t
Failure of development, or incomplete development, of a part of the body. 

noun
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an HEAD request

> The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that would be returned if the HEAD request's URL was instead requested with the HTTP GET method.

You want to do

```
URL = 'https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia'
page = requests.get(URL, allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: I mentioned that I had tried this, I'm not sure if it's worked for you, but for example doing `print(page.history) -> [<Response [302]>]` and `print(page.status_code) -> 200` shows that it isn't redirecting

Comment: @7kofnmip use `page.history[0].status_code` lol

Comment: @7koFnMiP Why did you write, that it is not redirecting, when you show that it is at the same time? 

Comment: * Not redirecting to the correct page, to clarify

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a pop-up window, Selenium.py is really good for scraping at a more user-friendly level. If you know the selector of the page element, you can scrape it with `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('theselector').text`
Where `driver = webdriver.chromedriver('file path')`.
This is a pretty radical circumvention of the problem so I understand if it's not applicable to your specific situation but hopefully you find this answer useful. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to use an API instead though as scraping even slightly quickly temporarily blocks access to the website

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia'
>>> requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True).url
'https://www.lexico.com/search?filter=en_dictionary&query=agenesia'
```

This is the URL that other commands find. For example, with curl:

```
$ curl -v https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesia 2>&1 | grep location:
< location: https://www.lexico.com/search?filter=en_dictionary&query=agenesia
```

Comment: But I'm not sure what this is meant to do? The `https://www.lexico.com/search?filter=en_dictionary&query=agenesia` url also doesn't redirect to `https://www.lexico.com/definition/agenesis` so it doesn't help in scraping the definition - see my recent post edit for how I am using it to scrape